# Java JIT a static non-volatile value changed , the access loop becomes a hundred times longer

Tags: java, loops, static, volatile, jit

There is a branch judgment on a non volatile static bool value in the loop. When the bool value is modified by other threads, the execution time of the whole loop becomes a hundred times longer, and jstack shows that the thread runs on the line acces

sample:

```
package test;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class StaticTest {

    static boolean tag = true;

    static HashSet<Integer> set = new HashSet<>();

    static boolean getTag(int i) {
        if (!tag) {
            return set.contains(i);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        for (int i = 0; i < 225 * 225 * 4; i++) {
            set.add(ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(0, 225 * 225 * 4));
        }

        Thread.sleep(5000);
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++) {
            Thread t = new Thread(() -> {
                while (true) {
                    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
                    HashMap<Integer, Boolean> iMap = new HashMap<>();
                    for (int j = 0; j < 225 * 225 * 4; j++) {
                        if (getTag(j)) {
                            iMap.put(j, true);
                        } else {
                            iMap.put(j, false);
                        }
                    }
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            t.start();
        }

        Thread.sleep(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(3));
        tag = true;
        System.out.println(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()));
        while (true) {
            Thread.sleep(10000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: There are many problems here. I would use JMH for benchmarking because it deals with a bunch of typical benchmark related problems like warmup. 

Does your machine have 128 cores? If not, what is the purpose of testing with 128 threads. Lot of time wasted on context switching.

Do not believe jstack. Get some proper profiling like the perf (which is a part of JMH). 

'tag' needs to be volatile. Currently you have a data race and your code might be doing something else than you expect it is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Correct benchmarking comes a bit short here, it seems.

The slow-down could very well be the `set.contains(i)` call, but it might also be a case  of deoptimization. Besides `volatile` you might consider one of the following.

I assume optimized usage is not the primary goal of the question, but one should nevertheless consider the data structures.

```
static BitSet set = new BitSet(225 * 225 * 4);

                BitSet iMap = BitSet(225 * 225 * 4);
                for (int j = 0; j < 225 * 225 * 4; j++) {
                    iMap.set(j, getTag(j);
                }
```

Or maybe best, if the result is not tri-state (false, true, null), or whether null can be reconstructed:

```
                Set<Integer> iNot = new HashSet<>();
                for (int j = 0; j < 225 * 225 * 4; j++) {
                    if (!getTag(j)) { // Most unlikely
                        iNot.add(j);
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The set.contain() in my example is a configuration in the actual environment, and the length is also within 1000. The execution branch is also an example. The map data structure is not used. When the tag is false, the execution time of the method is about 20ms. After the tag value is modified to true, the set.contain() is no longer judged, but the time is increased to 1500ms. I think the problem of the data structure can not explain the sudden increase in the execution time